# how do I fetch TCP initial sequence number from user space in Linux?

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

In order to track a TCP session as it traverses a network, I would like to know the Initial Sequence Number of the session. I have written some code to simply copy the ISN into the tcp_sock structure when the TCP session is created, then added code to copy that value into the tcp_info structure returned by getsockopt(). This seems to work, but I was wondering if there was a better way. I see that snt_isn and rcv_isn are stored in the structure tcp_request_sock. Is there a way to access the tcp_request_sock structure from the tp structure in getsockopt()?

thanks in advance
bvs

Comment: If you're tracking it on the network, you can grab the ISN from the SYN packet.  Note that a sequence number is not guaranteed to be unique: you need to qualify it with the connection 5-tuple (protocol, src ip, src port, dest ip, dest port).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way for a user-space to get (or set) the sequence numbers via the socket-API (e.g., via setsockopt or tcp_info,...).

The only way to read it would be by capturing the trace with tcpdump.